# hive Timestamp change while selecting

Tags: timestamp, hive

Example:

hive> "select timestamp('2015-03-08 **02**:01:00') from tablename limit 1;"

gives following answer: 2015-03-08 **03**:01:00

Same thing happens for all the stored timestamps. How can we stop this from happening?

Looks like its a timezone issue. Can someone point how can we change the default timezone at session level

Answer (score 0):

To return timestamp from String value use the below line of statement

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');
```

**Example**

```
 SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(('2015-03-08 02:01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:ii:ss'), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:ii:ss');
```

I hope you were searching something like this.

Comment: It still returns 2015-03-08 03:01:00 with SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-08 02:01:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')